# Jensen's inequality and convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

In my real analysis book i am given definition and theorem.

**Definition.**

Real function $f$ is convex on $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if $(\forall x_1,x_2 \in I)$ $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})\leq\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}.$

**Theorem(Jensen's inequality).**

Let $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be function defined on open interval $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Function $f$ is continious and convex on $I$ if and only if given inequality is satisfied

$(\forall x_1,x_2\in I)$,$(\forall t\in [ 0,1 ] )$,   $f((1-t)x_1+tx_2)\leq(1-t)f(x_1)+tf(x_2)$ $(4.29)$

If two sides in $(4.29)$ are equal for some $t\in \langle0,1\rangle$, then they are equal $\forall t\in [0,1]$

Question:

Isn't it enough for function to be convex that Jensen's inequality is satisfied for $t=\frac{1}{2}$. I am just reading the definition.

Comment: It is indeed enough, but *Jensen's inequality* is nevertheless  equivalent. 2Note the definition you have is sufficient because the set of $2$-adic fractions is dense in $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Lets say that Jensen's inequality is satisfied for $t=\frac{1}{2}$, but not for $t=0.7$, by definition function is convex, but if and only if in Jensen's inequality says that it isn't.

Comment: If the function is continuous, it is equivalent.